# Beautiful soup pareses in some cases but not in others. Why?

Tags: python, json, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to parse some JSON out of an HTML file.
Basically I am using to get all employee profiles out of a LinkedIn search result.
However, for some reason it does not work with companies that have more than 10 employees for some reason. 
Here is my code

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = requests.session()

def get_csrf_tokens():
    url = "https://www.linkedin.com/"
    req = s.get(url).text

    csrf_token = req.split('name="csrfToken" value=')[1].split('" id="')[0]
    login_csrf_token = req.split('name="loginCsrfParam" value="')[1].split('" id="')[0]

    return csrf_token, login_csrf_token


def login(username, password):
    url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit"
    csrfToken, loginCsrfParam = get_csrf_tokens()

    data = {
        'session_key': username,
        'session_password': password,
        'csrfToken': csrfToken,
        'loginCsrfParam': loginCsrfParam
    }

    req = s.post(url, data=data)
    print "success"

login(USERNAME PASSWORD)
def get_all_json(company_link):
    r=s.get(company_link)
    html= r.content
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
    html_file= open("html_file.html", 'w')
    html_file.write(html)
    html_file.close()
    Json_stuff=soup.find('code', id="voltron_srp_main-content")
    print Json_stuff
    return remove_tags(Json_stuff)
def remove_tags(p):
    p=str(p)
    return p[62: -10]

def list_of_employes():
    jsons=get_all_json('https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?f_CC=2409087')
    print jsons
    loaded_json=json.loads(jsons.replace(r'\u002d', '-'))
    employes=loaded_json['content']['page']['voltron_unified_search_json']['search']['results']
    return employes
def get_employee_link(employes):
    profiles=[]
    for employee in employes:
        print employee['person']['link_nprofile_view_3']
        profiles.append(employee['person']['link_nprofile_view_3'])
    return profiles , len(profiles)

print get_employee_link(list_of_employes())
```

It will not work for the link that is in place; however it will work for this company search: https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?f_CC=3003796

**EDIT**:
I am pretty sure that this is an error with the get_all_json() function. If 
you take a look, it does not correctly fetch the JSON for companies with more than 10 employees.

Comment: Are you using lxml or html5lib? Or just the Python standard lib HtmlParser? I don't know about the specifics of your situation but both lxml and html5lib are more robust than HtmlParser.

Comment: I am not sure. How do I check and how do I change it because I think that may be my problem here.

Comment: lxml and html5lib are not in the standard library, so if you haven't specifically installed either of those, you're probably using the standard lib HtmlParser. If you're not sure, you can check by doing "import lxml" or "import html5lib". If you get an ImportError, you don't have them.

Comment: ok, I tried both, I got the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the results are paginated. You need get over all pages defined inside the json data at:

```
data['content']['page']['voltron_unified_search_json']['search']['baseData']['resultPagination']['pages']
```

`pages` is a list, for the company `2409087` it is:

```
[{u'isCurrentPage': True, u'pageNum': 1, u'pageURL': u'http://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?f_CC=2409087&page_num=1'}, 
 {u'isCurrentPage': False, u'pageNum': 2, u'pageURL': u'http://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?f_CC=2409087&page_num=2', u'page_number_i18n': u'Page 2'}, 
 {u'isCurrentPage': False, u'pageNum': 3, u'pageURL': u'http://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?f_CC=2409087&page_num=3', u'page_number_i18n': u'Page 3'}]
```

This is basically a list of URLs you need to get over and get the data.

Here's what you need to do (ommiting the code for login):

```
def get_results(json_code):
    return json_code['content']['page']['voltron_unified_search_json']['search']['results']

url = "https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?f_CC=2409087"
soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).text)

code = soup.find('code', id="voltron_srp_main-content").contents[0].replace(r'\u002d', '-')
json_code = json.loads(code)

results = get_results(json_code)

pages = json_code['content']['page']['voltron_unified_search_json']['search']['baseData']['resultPagination']['pages']
for page in pages[1:]:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(page['pageURL']).text)
    code = soup.find('code', id="voltron_srp_main-content").contents[0].replace(r'\u002d', '-')
    json_code = json.loads(code)
    results += get_results(json_code)

print len(results)
```

It prints `25` for https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?f_CC=2409087 - exactly how much you see in browser.

Comment: Hey thanks for this answer. It helps, but it does not really address the question. The problem with my code now is that beautiful soup is not getting the JSON

Comment: @JONPON ok, the code I've provided is actually parsing it, it's the working code and looks like it does what you wanted..

Comment: Yes it is. But that is considering you get the JSON code. You see, the problem with my code is that BS4 does not get the JSON when I use links with more than 10 employees. Instead of returning the json surrounded by the <code></code> tags it just returns the <code></code> with nothing in them.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a problem with the default BeautifulSoup parser.
I changed it to html5lib by doing this:

Install in the console

```
pip install html5lib
```

And change the type of parser you choose when first creating the soup object.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
```

This is documented in the [BeautifulSoup docs here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)